# Horizontal spacing in tcblistof (from tcolorbox)

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

I have a spacing issue with more than 10 listed boxes in 2-digit chapters:

[image]

What parameter do I need to adjust to use a wider label, i.e., more space between `24.42` and `An`?  The list is created as `\tcblistof[\section*]{lis}{List of Listings}`.

[EDIT]
Adding a self-contained LaTeX file:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,
               number within=chapter,
               crefname={lis.}{lis.},
               Crefname={Listing}{Listings},
               list inside=lis,
              ]{labelboxcode}[4][]{%
    listing options={language=#2,#1},
    list text={#4},
    label=#3,
    listing only
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{23}
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@labelboxcode}{41}

\begin{labelboxcode}{Scala}{scala-listing}{A Scala program.}
def abs(x: Int) = if x > 0 then x else -x
\end{labelboxcode}

\tcblistof[\section*]{lis}{List of Listings}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimum compilable code from  `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. The packages used and the setting of  `tcolorbox ` are important to solve the issue.  A single chapter a three boxes will be enough.  Use `\setcounter{chapter}{24}` to produce double digits chapters.

Comment: It's not easy to produce a short example, given the many definitions involved.  If `tcblistof` is expected to handle such wide labels, I'll create a standalone example. I was hoping someone would just know of a length that needs to be set to accommodate the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: b]

Try this code with your document. (Added a small space before the title)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,
number within=chapter,
crefname={lis.}{lis.},
Crefname={Listing}{Listings},
list inside=lis,
]{labelboxcode}[4][]{%
    listing options={language=#2,#1},
    list text={\hspace*{1ex}#4}, %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
    label=#3,
    listing only
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@labelboxcode}{0}

\begin{labelboxcode}{Scala}{scala-listing}{A Scala program I}
def abs(x: Int) = if x > 0
\end{labelboxcode}

\newpage
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@labelboxcode}{11}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\begin{labelboxcode}{Scala}{scala-listing}{A Scala program II}
def abs(x: Int) = if x > 0
\end{labelboxcode}

    \newpage
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@labelboxcode}{33}
\setcounter{page}{12}

\begin{labelboxcode}{Scala}{scala-listing}{A Scala program III}
def abs(x: Int) = if x > 0
\end{labelboxcode}

\newpage
\setcounter{chapter}{23}
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@labelboxcode}{0}
\setcounter{page}{103}

\begin{labelboxcode}{Scala}{scala-listing}{A Scala program IV}
def abs(x: Int) = if x > 0
\end{labelboxcode}

    \newpage
\setcounter{chapter}{23}
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@labelboxcode}{41}
\setcounter{page}{150}

\begin{labelboxcode}{Scala}{scala-listing}{A Scala program V}
def abs(x: Int) = if x > 0
\end{labelboxcode}

\newpage    
\tcblistof[\section*]{lis}{List of Listings}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was easy enough.