# \tcblistof: How to change horizontal spacing in generated list of theorem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

I've defined a `tcbtheorem` (using `\newtcbtheorem`}, and use `\tcblistof` to create a "List of Theorems", similar to List of Figures and List of Tables. All pretty standard.

The list that comes out is fine, except that the horizontal space between the theorem identifier and its short title is too small. How can this be increased/edited?

For comparison, this space can be changed for the standard List of Figures using this command, using the `tocloft` package:

```
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}
```

So I'm looking to do the same, but now for the list generated by `\tcblistof`
This issue:
[Horizontal spacing in tcblistof (from tcolorbox)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618572/horizontal-spacing-in-tcblistof-from-tcolorbox)
is related, but only considers `tcblistings`, which seems to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and after a bit of searching, and based on [this existing answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217489/numbering-tcolorbox-toc), this is what I put together with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
% no indent for entries
\renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox[list inside=remarkblocks]{remarkblock}[1]
  { enhanced
  , colframe=red!15!lightgray
  , colback=red!50!gray!5
  , fonttitle=\bfseries
  , title=#1
  , list entry=#1
  }

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\begin{remarkblock}{A first remark}
\lipsum[1]
\end{remarkblock}

\begin{remarkblock}{A second remark}
\lipsum[1]
\end{remarkblock}

\tcblistof[\section*]{remarkblocks}{List of remarks}

\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image: Rendered content, titles only, no indent]